# Firebase database update google pay translation details

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-pay

If someone send me money to my google pay is there any way to update that info in my firebase database only for personal use (no company registration)

Comment: Hi Midhilaj, are you referring to receiving funds through peer to peer payments?